# Eclipse AST variable binding on standalone java application

Tags: java, code-analysis, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to use Eclipse ASTParser in order to analyse and, if possible, add some code to some classes. One of the information I need requires to have bindings, but because this is a standalone project (the final goal it's a command line tool, independent from eclipse) I can't have them (`requireBinding()` returns `null`).

After reading a lot of posts, the far that I can go is using [this examples](http://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/tools/org.eclipse.objectteams/trunk/testplugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core.tests.compiler/src/org/eclipse/jdt/core/tests/dom/StandAloneASTParserTest.java) in order to use `FileASTRequestor` but that's not the way to go since it seems to me that we have to give the KEY to bind before generating the AST tree.

I've found somewhere that we can use [ASTParser.setEnvironment](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTParser.html#setEnvironment%28java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20boolean%29) method in order to use the bindings in a standalone java application, but I don't think I'm doing it correctly. What's wrong with the code below?

```
private static final String rootDir = "D:\\workspace\\stateless\\";
    private static final String[] classpath = java.lang.System.getProperty( "java.class.path" ).split(";");

    private static final String source = 
            "package de.siemens.tools.stateless.test.examples; " +
            "public class ClassWithFinalMemberVariables {" +
            "private final int _memberIntVariable = 0;" +
            "public void method() {" +
            "int localVariable = 0;" +
            "System.out.println(_memberIntVariable + localVariable);" +
            "}" +
            "}";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CoreException {

        Document document = new Document(source);
        ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS4);
        parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
        parser.setEnvironment(classpath, new String[] { rootDir }, 
new String[] { "UTF8" }, true);  
        parser.setSource(document.get().toCharArray());
        parser.setResolveBindings(true);
        parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);
        CompilationUnit unit = (CompilationUnit)parser.createAST(null);

        unit.recordModifications();

        unit.accept(new ASTVisitor() {

@Override
            public void endVisit(VariableDeclarationFragment node) {

                IVariableBinding bind = node.resolveBinding();

                if(bind == null) 
                   System.out.println("ERROR: bind is null");

                super.endVisit(node);
            }
```

Output is always "`ERROR: bind is null`".

Comment: What does it print if you add an else branch? `if(bind == null) System.out.println("ERROR: bind is null"); else System.out.println("ERROR: bind is not null");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've already solved it, the code is here:
http://pasteit.com/19433

Even though I prefer the ASTVisitor model, this one gives me every binding available.

And here is the discussion about the problem, for those of you who are curious: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=206391

**EDIT:** I don't have any idea if this is the best solution or not, if you have any suggestion please let me know

Comment: Hi! By any chance could you paste your code once again somewhere, because the original paste link does not work anymore! Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @MarekSzanyi sorry but I don't have that code with me anymore, the only thing I remember about this it's that I've changed to AspectJ, it was best suited (aka less time to market) for that particular job. What do you want to do?